# how to check pstack of a process which is running under valgrind

Tags: linux, process, valgrind

I am running a process(process-x) using valgrind.I want to check the pstack of the process.
I can see only the pstack of valgrind process not the pstack of process-x ..

is there any command to check the same ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that by 'check the pstack of the process', you mean that you want to look at the current stack trace of the process running under valgrind.

One way to do that is to use gdb+vgdb to debug your program running under valgrind. You can then use gdb to examine the stack trace of your program,
values of variables, put breakpoints, ...

See https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more information.

Another option is to use vgdb from the shell and do:

> vgdb  v.info scheduler